# How do i extract the length of integer array from Map<int , int[] >?

Tags: java, dictionary, entryset

How do i extract the length of integer array from a `Map?

```
Map <Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> res = function() ;

for (Map.Entry entry : res.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getValue());        
}
```

Doing `System.out.println(entry.getValue().size());` does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify type arguments for your `Entry`.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : res.entrySet()){
```

Otherwise, the type usage is *raw*.

See

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: 100% thx, i felt like there was something obvious, but i did not know about this stuff - still lots of java to learn.!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing generic thing when you are retrieving the MAP 
try below line

```
  for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : res.entrySet())
```